# Как в C можно перевернуть слова?

Tags: c

Пример: слово Hello будет написана olleH.

Пытаюсь одним array бежать с начала, а другим - с конца и вставлять буквы.

Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void mahaph(char str[]){

    int total = strlen(str);

    char temp[10];

    for (int i = total, int j = 0; i <= 0 j > total; i--, j++){

        temp[j] = str[i];

    }

    printf("%s\n", temp[i]);
}

void main(){

    char str[] = "Hello";

}
```

Comment: @David Kern, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @David Kern, надеюсь это будет просто и понятно.


    char *
    copy_reverse (char src[], char dst[])
    {
      int len = strlen(src), i = len - 1, j = 0;
    
      while (i >= 0)
        dst[j++] = src[i--];
      dst[j] = 0;
    
      return dst;
    }
    
    int
    main (int ac, char *av[])
    {
      if (av[1]) {
        char buf[strlen(av[1]) + 1];
    
        puts(copy_reverse(av[1], buf));
      }
    
      return puts("End") == EOF;
    }

Если вопросы остались -- задавайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитывая тот факт, что в C нет строк как типа данных, а есть массивы символов

```
char myString[10]
```

последним элементом которого всегда является '\0' - нулевой символ, используйте то, что применимо к массивам.

```
int len = sizeof(str)-1; // длина строки/размер массива за вычетом '\0'
// учтите, что для русского текста каждый char весит 2 байта.
printf("%i\t%c\n",i, str[i]); // печать содержимого в цикле
```

В самом грубом виде ваша задача выглядит так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  char str[]="hello";
  char temp[6];
  int len = sizeof(str)-1;
  int i = 0;
  for (i=0; i<len;i++) {
    temp[len-i-1] = str[i];
    printf("%d\t%c\t%d\t%c\n", i, str[i], len-i-1, temp[len-i-1]);
  }
  temp[len+1] = '\0';
  printf ("%s, %d\n", str, len);
  printf ("%s, %d\n", temp, sizeof(temp)-1);
```

Comment: Oгромное Cпасибо :))))

Comment: `char` по определению имеет размер один байт, а не два. Если говорить про Юникодные символы (например, русский текст), то кол-во байт зависит от (нормализации и) кодировки такой как utf-8, utf-16le, cp1251, cp866. Если предположить, что закодированные символы (байты) хранятся в `str`, то нельзя обратить слово в многобайтовых кодировках простым обращением массива, например [`{209, 132, 0}` массив является буковкой `ф` в utf-8](http://ideone.com/YzeVqw) -- если перевернуть этот массив, то ничего осмысленного не получится (перевёрнутые байты не являются корректным utf-8 текстом).

Comment: Да. Вы правы. Код который я показал - действительно годится только для однобайтных кодировок. И насчет "char весит 2 байта" - это конечно я сильно не прав. Наверно, более верным будет сказать, что символы кодируются 2-ми или более байтами.

Для более универсального решения нужно использовать что-то вроде wchar_t и/или какую-нть библиотеку для работы с Unicode. На самом деле мои знания о C весьма поверхностны.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>  // putchar

void rev(const char* const c)
{
    if (*c)
    {
        rev(c + 1);
        putchar(*c);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    rev("Hello!");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не так давно понадобилось переставить буквы в словах, но порядок слов сохранить. Взял предлагаемую здесь на форуме строку кода и перевернул два раза с небольшими модификациями.

```
function reverser(sentence) {
    sentence = sentence.split('').reverse().join('');
    return sentence.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
}

let sentence = "Hello World";
console.log(reverser(sentence));
```

Comment: Вопрос по языку Си

Comment: Вы правы. Удалите пожалуйста мой пост.